# EditText revert back to grey text when disabled

Tags: java, android

I am trying to disable a edittext view when I click on a checkbox. My only issue is that when I disable the edittext using the checkbox, the edittext field is still pink as if a cursor was still inside of it waiting for input.

[image]

[image]

How can I change that edittext color back to the normal state after the checkbox has been clicked? Here is the code I have so far:

```
            if (mAnonymousCheckBox.isChecked()) {

                // remove preferences
                usernameEditText.setFocusable(false);
                usernameEditText.setEnabled(false);
                setFTPUsername("");
                setFTPPassword("");
            }
```